# Insert http request header for debugging

Tags: django, httprequest

I'm testing a Django application on my local environment using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

When the app is running in production, the client has a web proxy that validates you against AD and inserts a http header. But for debugging, I can't run though that proxy. In order to test, I've been using the Firefox plugin "Modify Headers" to insert a version of this header, but now I've got a bug that requires me to insert that header in IE. I'd rather not modify the source because there is a risk that it might end up getting checked in, so I'm looking for something I can either put in the app settings.py or a script or something I can run between the testing server and the client (but which doesn't require anything to be installed because everything is locked down here).

Comment: why you dont create a new settings file named test_settings? So it will be used only when you run your tests ... You also can override your settings with a decorator

Comment: I don't mind changing the settings.py file, I'm just not sure how I'd change the header in the settings.py file.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say this is your settings.py:

```
VARIABLE_THAT_YOU_NEED = "VALUE A"
```

In the end of your settings file you just have to add this line:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
try:
    from test_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Now you create a new file named "test_settings.py", inside of this file you override ONLY what you need for testing, in your case:

```
VARIABLE_THAT_YOU_NEED = "VALUE B"
```

So, when you run your server, you will have your variable normally and when run tests this variable will be replaced!

Comment: Who does this modify what's in your HTTPRequest headers?

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry.